# Why am I stuck in a while loop?[c++]

Tags: c++, vector, random, graph

I'm stuck in a loop in here. I have a matrix filled with zeroes and I want to add k edges to a graph. I have no errors showed in Visual Studio. While it goes to this line of code:

```
int z = 0;
    while (z!=k);
    {
        int a = std::rand() % n;
        int b = std::rand() % n;
        if ((v[a][b] != 1) && (a != b))
        {
            v[a][b] = 1;
            v[b][a] = 1;
            z++;
        }
    }
```

program gets stuck in infinite loop;

Here is full code:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> random_gnk(int n, int k)
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int temp = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        temp = temp + i;
    }
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> v;
    if (k > temp || k<0)
    {
        std::cout << "Blad. Podano zla liczbe krawedzi." << std::endl;
        return v;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        std::vector<int>row;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        {
            row.push_back(0);
        }
        v.push_back(row);
    }

    int z = 0;
    while (z!=k);
    {
        int a = std::rand() % n;
        int b = std::rand() % n;
        if ((v[a][b] != 1) && (a != b))
        {
            v[a][b] = 1;
            v[b][a] = 1;
            z++;
        }
    }
    return v;
}
void GNK()
{
    int n, k;
    std::cout << "Podaj wielkosc n grafu: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> n;
    std::cout << "Podaj liczbe k krawedzi grafu: " << std::endl;
    std::cin >> k;
    print_matrix(random_gnk(n, k));
    return;
}
```

Comment: Could we see the declaration of n, v, and k?

Comment: What happens when you step through this with the debugger?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Besides the definitions of the unknown variables, also please show how you initialize them, and what their values are.

Comment: While I use debugger it gets stuck after while (z!=k);
    {

Comment: n=5,k=2 , It looks like this before while loop and After I step over http://imgur.com/a/jGpjp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your code through `clang-format`:

```
  int z = 0;
  while (z != k)
    ;
  {
```

This should be clear: remove the semicolon!

There's an online formatter [here](http://format.krzaq.cc/). If you like it, get it set up with your IDE or code editor. It will solve problems like this and make your code more beautiful.

Comment: My god, I feel so stupid right now. It was a simple ; It works, Thank you very much!

Comment: :) Seriously - use `clang-format`. Makes coding much more fun!

Comment: I flagged this question for closing as it's a simple typo - however maybe it should stand as stray `;`s are a problem which happens a lot.